# Multi language field on keystone

Tags: keystonejs

I have an String field like this on a kestonejs model.

`text: { type: String },`

¿What is the best way for supporting multi language in that field?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [mongoose-intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-intl) Mongoose plugin to have your `String` properties support languages other than English. Keystone [supports Mongoose plugins](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-plugins), so you should be able to associate the plugin with your Keystone model as you would a normal Mongoose model.

Comment: But in the admin how is going to look?

Comment: I actually just tried it out, and it looks like other languages are natively supported. See [this image](http://i.imgur.com/npKsEwB.png) to see how it looks in the Admin UI.

Comment: I don't understand, I don't want to translate the admin. I want a field that can contain a different text for each language.

Comment: To clarify: you want one singular field to have multiple sub-fields in different languages?

Comment: yes, exactly that. now I'm doing this… http://pastebin.com/raw/dubbNrmq


It's an ugly code and it's very bad looking in the admin

Comment: Keystone itself doesn't natively support other languages. Using nested fields like that is the only solution that I can think of, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

a field may not be the answer, but you can try an key => value system like http://i18next.com/docs/ this will help you detect the language of user, translate serverside in routes or in templates as you like.